# How to get a code signing for excel addin exe files on a trial version basis?

Tags: code-signing, excel-addins

I am looking to release an excel addin I built on my website, which the user's will download and install. It also has an auto update feature. 
My problem is when the auto update feature runs it is not allowed save files to the user's machine because I dont have any code signing certificate I assume. 
So, right now I am looking for a trial version of code signing certificate. 
Does any one know about these things ?
Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use SSL certificate. There are millions of SSL certificates available for free and trial version in the market. Google for SSL certificates.

Comment: As per my knowledge...One cant use SSL to do code signing....please correct me if I am wrong....